# When asking about an advertised method, does refering to it necessary?

Tags: discussion, references

[My question](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/10291/99) asks about the scientificity of an advertised method. A commenter says that there is no necessity to link that ad. I agree, but I guess linking it as a reference is not a wrong thing to do. After all, I am asking for a source, then it's fair to cite the source that I suspect, right?

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the ad and the circumstances. In this case, it was a link to a video that was purely an ad for a product. I don't think anybody needed to watch a video to get the idea. A simple description would have sufficed. So the end result is it makes your question seem rather spammy.

It also means if that video is ever deleted, your question will make no sense. Instead of a link to the ad itself, a better link would be a text description of the product, or just your own description.

So I think it's best to link to ads only when they're 1) necessary to understand the question (or answer), and 2) there isn't a better,  non-commercial source available. In this case I think it failed test #1.

Comment: I think in all cases the question should be understood by itself so that there is no need to visit the links, and usually any ad should be easy-to-digest enough for the viewer to describe it to someone else  At the time of writing the question, I also saw that adding the link make the question feels like a spam post. But at least I'm glad to see the answer for ad sources.

Comment: I agree that questions should stand on their own. There's nothing more frustrating than finding the question or answer you need, only to discover that the link it relies on is dead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding the link is necessary, but it certainly doesn't hurt. It's up to the reader to decide whether to see the advertisement. Broken links are always an issue, but as long as the question is self-contained, there's nothing the OP can do about it (aside from mirroring somewhere else), and it's not specific to advertisements.

Comment: I don't think it doesn't hurt. At least, it creates a cognitive workload on the reader to decide to click on it or not. That's why we have to know a little in designing. I agree with the rest.

Comment: @Ooker "That's why we have to know a little in designing. " -> what do you mean?

Comment: you can strip that bit without changing the meaning of my previous comment. It's a little far from the cognitive workload perspective. What I mean is that knowing some design principles can help you know how to display an element that eases the readers, which at the core is still mitigate their cognitive workload.

Comment: I think it does hurt. For example, it leads readers to click on a link that's merely a commercial ad and therefore can't be trusted to be even vaguely accurate. It also can't be trusted not to drop tracking cookies, start blaring sound unexpectedly, or display NSFW ads or content. If readers don't **need** to see it to understand the question, then why is it there? And saying users can ignore it is placing the onus on readers to self-edit questions to make them good questions. I find it extremely rare that explaining something requires an ad, and especially not a video.

Comment: As for dead links, people can quote the essentials from a site to protect against it going dead, but there's no way to "quote" a video. Once it goes dead, that's it.